# Calculate reputation percentage based on negative and positive

Tags: javascript, php, math

I have users which can receive up-votes on their posts.
Example:
5 users upvote
2 users downvote.
I need to calculate the percentage of positive feedback.

I try with this code:

```php
$result=(($positive-$negative)/$negative);
$r = ($result*100);
$result = $r / 100;
```

The code above does not work because if i have 50 upvotes and 1 downvote, The percentage results in 49%.

Comment: https://www.wikihow.com/Calculate-Percentages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If 50 votes is 100%, you need to calculate percentage for 49 votes. Here is the math:

```
/* 50(votes) / 100% = 49(votes) / $x% */
$x = 100 x 49 / 50;
```

Which is `98%`

For 5 upvotes and 2 down votes you can use the same logic:

```
$x = 100 x 3 / 5;
```

Which is `60%`

Comment: You're welcome :) As long as you live, so long do you learn.